# How to setup a scheduled task in Windows XP to run a Marcro in ms-access?

Tags: ms-access, macros, scheduled-tasks

I typically have some need to run a process each day prior to my arrival at the office. I would like to set this up as a scheduled task.

How can this be accomplished?

Is there a best practice on doing this?

Can or should this be done programmatically?

Comment: What kind of process is it? Running a query? Printing a report? Emailing something?

Comment: It is running a Macro which does various things, including the execution of code.

Comment: That's not an answer to the question at all. A good answer on how to do this properly requires knowing exactly which kinds of tasks are being performed, because the approach for how to accomplish it depends on what the tasks are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve this I did the following:

- Created a Macro named "Submit".
- Created a Scheduled task `.job` file by going to:

  `Start > All Programs > Accessories > System Tools > Schedule Tasks`

[image: Scheduled Task Dialog Box]

(This produced the `.job` file in the following location: "C:\WINDOWS\Tasks\Submit.job")

Once this was created, I placed the following syntax into the `Run:` text box.

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office11\MSACCESS.EXE"  "C:\MyDatabasePath\MyDatabaseName.mdb" /x "Submit"
```

After this, the remaining portion of the setup is completed as a normal schedule task should be. You can find more details about how to manually setup these tasks [here][2] or if you like to perform the setup through the command line, [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313565) is a particularly useful reference.

Note: Both the Macro and the job file must be setup for this to work correctly.

One way to accomplish this programmatically would be do utilize the job API's. Here is one such example where this was accomplished using VBA:

[See Reference Here](http://www.andreavb.com/forum/viewtopic_1507.html)

```
Option Explicit
' Schedule api's
Declare Function NetScheduleJobAdd Lib "netapi32.dll" _
(ByVal Servername As String, Buffer As Any, Jobid As Long) As Long

' Schedule structure
Type AT_INFO
    JobTime     As Long
    DaysOfMonth As Long
    DaysOfWeek  As Byte
    Flags       As Byte
    dummy       As Integer
    Command     As String
End Type

' Schedule constants
Const JOB_RUN_PERIODICALLY = &H1
Const JOB_NONINTERACTIVE = &H10
Const NERR_Success = 0

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim lngWin32apiResultCode As Long
    Dim strComputerName As String
    Dim lngJobID As Long
    Dim udtAtInfo As AT_INFO

    ' Convert the computer name to unicode
    strComputerName = StrConv(Text1.Text, vbUnicode)

    ' Setup the tasks parameters
    SetStructValue udtAtInfo

    ' Schedule the task
    lngWin32apiResultCode = NetScheduleJobAdd(strComputerName, udtAtInfo, lngJobID)

    ' Check if the task was scheduled
    If lngWin32apiResultCode = NERR_Success Then
        MsgBox "Task" & lngJobID & " has been scheduled."
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub SetStructValue(udtAtInfo As AT_INFO)
    Dim strTime As String
    Dim strDate() As String
    Dim vntWeek() As Variant
    Dim intCounter As Integer
    Dim intWeekCounter As Integer

    vntWeek = Array("M", "T", "W", "TH", "F", "S", "SU")

    With udtAtInfo

        ' Change the format of the time
        strTime = Format(Text2.Text, "hh:mm")

        ' Change the time to one used by the api
        .JobTime = (Hour(strTime) * 3600 + Minute(strTime) * 60) * 1000

        ' Set the Date parameters
        If Val(Text3.Text) > 0 Then

            ' Set the task to run on specific days of the month i.e. 9th & 22nd of the month
            strDate = Split(Text3.Text, ",")
            For intCounter = 0 To UBound(strDate)
                .DaysOfMonth = .DaysOfMonth + 2 ^ (strDate(intCounter) - 1)
            Next

        Else

            ' Set the task to run on sepecific days of the week i.e. Monday & Thursday
            strDate = Split(Text3.Text, ",")
            For intCounter = 0 To UBound(strDate)
                For intWeekCounter = 0 To UBound(vntWeek)
                    If UCase(strDate(intCounter)) = vntWeek(intWeekCounter) Then
                        .DaysOfWeek = .DaysOfWeek + 2 ^ intWeekCounter
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End If

        ' Set the interactive property
        If Check1.Value = vbUnchecked Then
            .Flags = .Flags Or JOB_NONINTERACTIVE
        End If

        ' Set to run periodically
        If Option2.Value = True Then
            .Flags = .Flags Or JOB_RUN_PERIODICALLY
        End If

        ' Set the command to run
        .Command = StrConv(Text4.Text, vbUnicode)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Curtis, is it possible for this to work while the user is logged out (uncheck "Run only if logged on")? Doesn't seem to work for me but I would like it to work without an active user session.

Comment: Not sure. Never tried without an active user session. Sorry :/

Answer (score 1):

If the tasks do not run appropriately, it may be due to updates in software and/or service packs. Check the program files for Microsoft Office and Access. "Office11" as shown in the run line may need to be changed to "Office 14" or "Office12" depending on the folders showing in program files.